# Можно в тэг ссылки(а) можно вкладывать абзацы(p)?

Tags: html, css

html 5

Можно в тэг ссылки(а) можно вкладывать абзацы(p)?

Comment: можно, но не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно

```css
a > div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1382192"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p></a>

<p><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1382192">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1382192"><div>Даже тут можно</div></a>

<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1382192"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"></a>
```

Comment: Вопрос был наоборот: можно ли абзацы помещать в ссылки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут и абзацы в ссылке и ссылки в абзацы)

Comment: Только правильный ответ другой: помещать физически-то можно что угодно во что угодно, не не стОит по ряду причин.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему не стоит? Заключить абзац в ссылку абсолютно легитимный приём, как с точки зрения спецификации HTML, так и в плане практической целесообразности. Например, это может быть какой-то тексто-графический блок (снипет), целиком являющийся одной ссылкой.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov по спецификации можно и слона в муху завернуть. Но на сколько это правильно с точки зрения здравого смысла? А если у вас целый параграф - ссылка - печально. Потому что обычно делают ссылки вида "Читать далее", а не этого раздутого монстра

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я думаю это уже решение тому кто это сделает, хочет так или наоборот, главное ему помочь а дальше сам пусть решает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мы не знаем задачи, поэтому не можем рекомендовать (стоит или не стоит). Если это рекламный блок, которым автор на кусок хлеба зарабатывает, то будучи целой ссылкой он даст больший CTR, чем если целиться в одно слово. В текущей поставке вопроса ответ: "Можно"